# My CNN seems to reach a certain loss threshold, then stops learning from there

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I wasn't sure how to phrase this question, but yeah.
My CNN ([code here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/theonlytophat/cifar-classifier-v2)) keeps getting up to an accuracy of around 66% until it stops learning anymore. It just keeps fluctuating around the 66% range. I've been tuning hyper-parameters, but I just can't get it to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check the linked thread for many good hints.

Comment: i have checked that thread many-a-times.

Comment: Then, if you made sure everything works fine, you either need to better tune the model, try a different model, or there is always a chance that the problem is hopeless in the sense that better performance is not possible on this data.

Comment: sounds good, i'll try it.

Comment: Plus the usual suspects: improve data cleaning, preprocessing, feature engineering, get better and more data.